# Redraw window using DirectX during move/resize

Tags: winapi, directx, directx-11

I've followed this tutorial and got it all working: http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=InitDX11

The result is a window with a constantly changing background color. The trouble is that the color stops changing while the window is being dragged around. I've tried adding the following case statements (in various combinations) to the `WndProc` callback, but to no avail:

```
case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
  SetTimer(hwnd, 1, USER_TIMER_MINIMUM, NULL);
  return 0;

case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
  KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
  return 0;

case WM_TIMER:
  RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
  return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
  UpdateScene();
  DrawScene();
  return 0;
```

The above causes an exception at `d3d11DevCon->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, bgColor)`, but I've also tried merging the `WM_PAINT` case into the `WM_TIMER` case, and all I got was flickering between the natural window background color and the current color of the DX scene (the color of the DX portion of the flicker never evolved, it stayed constant no matter for how long I dragged the window).

Any tips?

Comment: @Alex: That's not it. The problem isn't that the message loop only updates when the message queue is empty. The issue is rather, that the message loop doesn't run at all, when moving/resizing the window. When moving/resizing a window, the code enters a modal (nested) loop, similar to a modal dialog. Until the operation is finished, the outer message loop will not run. The code should work as posted, although a `RDW_UPDATENOW` flag in the `RedrawWindow` call would more closely resemble the message loop behavior.

Comment: @Alex: The modal loop during moving/resizing will dispatch messages just fine. It's the custom loop implementation that won't run when inside the modal loop.

Comment: But wait, aren't timer messages lower priority than paint messages? If the timer is firing but no paint messages are sent, then what's going on? Is the inner modal loop during resizing an entirely different beast from every other message loop in the entire system?

Comment: @andlabs: Where did you get the idea from, that no paint messages were generated?

Comment: @IInspectable I think from Alex's comments, but they're deleted now so I can't quote them :/ The behavior described in the original post also seemed to imply this, given how it describes the background not changing.

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to just not draw while in a resize. There's not usually a lot of value in having the backbuffer resized over and over again. Just wait until the resize is complete to resize the buffer.

```
static bool s_in_sizemove = false;
static bool s_in_suspend = false;
static bool s_minimized = false;

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;

case WM_SIZE:
    if (wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
    {
        if (!s_minimized)
        {
            s_minimized = true;
            if (!s_in_suspend)
                OnSuspending();
            s_in_suspend = true;
        }
    }
    else if (s_minimized)
    {
        s_minimized = false;
        if (s_in_suspend)
            OnResuming();
        s_in_suspend = false;
    }
    else if ( !s_in_sizemove )
        OnWindowSizeChanged();
    break;

case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
    s_in_sizemove = true;
    break;

case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
    s_in_sizemove = false;
    OnWindowSizeChanged();
    break;

case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
    {
        auto info = reinterpret_cast<MINMAXINFO*>(lParam);
        info->ptMinTrackSize.x = 320;
        info->ptMinTrackSize.y = 200;
    }
    break;
```

You have to release all the backbuffer and depth-buffer references and recreate them in `OnWindowSizedChange`.

The actual rendering is done as part of the message pump for most 'real-time' graphics apps:

```
// Main message loop
MSG msg = { 0 };
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        Tick();
    }
}
```

Here `Tick` handles a timer update and the render.

See the [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) for a complete example.

**Update**: If the 'blank window' bothers you during the resize, but you are fine with the default behavior of `DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH` during the resize, you can replace the `WM_PAINT` above with:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    if (s_in_sizemove)
    {
        game->Tick();
    }
    else
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I thought solution would be complicated. However, no. That is about mesage pool. DX should use same thread and indeed you use your rendering (Ex: myRender(){..} ) in that loop In my case **Frame();** is the bool returnable I use for rendering that contains all operatios :

```
    MSG msg;
    bool done, result;
    
    // Initialize the message structure.
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    
    // Loop until there is a quit message from the window or the user.
    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        // Handle the windows messages.
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
    
        }
    
        // If windows signals to end the application then exit out.
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise do the frame processing.
            result = Frame();
            if (!result)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

When you resize you can handle some messages **WM_SIZE** or **WM_MOVE** message.  In your LRESULT CALLBACK handle:

```
            LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
                //...OTHERS...
                if (umessage == WM_MOVE) {
    
                  /*Dont be confused ApplicationHandle is pointer of my SystemClass
                    which set ApplicationHandle = this in SystemClass.
                    to create a window/s and Graphics (contains all DirectX related operations).
                    Here GraphicsClass (contains all DX calls) initialized in
                    SystemClass as new class and SystemClass initialized as
                    new class at main.cpp in WINAPI. That makes a lot easier
                    for handling this kind of issues for me
    
                    In your case you will call your rendering loop instead Frame();*/
    
                  if (ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics) {
                    RECT r;
                    GetClientRect(ApplicationHandle -> m_hwnd, & r);
                    ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics -> clientSize = {
                      r.right - r.left,
                      r.bottom - r.top
                    };
                    //frame processing.
                    ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics -> Frame();
                  }
                  if (umessage == WM_SIZING) {
                      if ((wparam == WMSZ_BOTTOM || wparam == WMSZ_RIGHT || wparam == WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT) && ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics) {
                      /*IF WE DO NOT HANDLE wparam resize will be very laggy.*/
                        GetClientRect(ApplicationHandle -> m_hwndOWNER, & clientRect);
                        ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics -> clientSize = {
                          clientRect.right - clientRect.left,
                          clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top
                        };
                        ApplicationHandle -> m_Graphics -> Frame();
    
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  //...OTHERS...
                }
```

HERE IS A VIDEO OF RESULT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vN_XPVRHuiw&feature=youtu.be

**even if you are drawing custom window using Desktop Window Manager (WDM) you can handle** *WM_NCHITTEST* **for other click situations as that will only update if you resize and move but not if you click and hold caption or hold border only.**

additionally, I did not get that why you handle **WM_PAINT** if you are using DirectX already.